# Problem creating an edit link for a custom post type

Tags: links, urls

In my last question, I asked [How to build a post and comment editing form in a page?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11382/how-to-build-a-post-and-comment-editing-form-in-a-page).

But in order to edit the custom post type (called Question) I have to reference the **edit page** and the **ID** of the custom post type.

I created a file called **edit-question.php** (located in the theme's folder).

And created a page called **Edit Question** in the Wordpress admin panel (and assigned the template file **edit-question.php** to it).

And placed the following code to display the edit link right before the loops ends (**loop-question.php**):

```
    <?php endif; // This was the if statement that broke the loop into three parts based on categories. ?>

    <?php if ($post->post_author = $current_user->ID) : ?>
        <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/edit-question.php?qpost_id=<?php $post->ID ?>">Edit!</a>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endwhile; // End the loop. Whew. ?>
```

When I click the **Edit!** link I get the following in my URL bar: `http://localhost/qaf/edit-question.php?qpost_id=`.

Looking at the default edit link of Wordpress looks like this:

```
http://localhost/qaf/wp-admin/post.php?post=61&action=edit
```

I think I have to make something similar except the `action=edit` part (not very sure).

What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: You need to echo the $post->ID so just add echo before it. And you don't need the edit action that is for the admin side and not the frontend

Comment: or simply use wordpress function `<?php the_ID() ?>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regularly You have this:

```
<?php edit_post_link( $link, $before, $after, $id ); ?>
```

In this example use "echo"

```
<?php echo $post->ID ?>">
```

Instead:

```
<?php $post->ID ?>">
```